# Does NSArray's filteredArrayUsingPredicate: create copies of the objects?

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsarray

I have an `NSArray`, which represents people. I use one of the properties of the `Person` class to filter the array and get another `NSArray` using a predicate.

```
   NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Favorite == %@", @"YES" ];
   NSArray *favorites = [people filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Does the new `NSArray`, `favorites`, maintain a copy of the people, or a reference pointing to the old `NSArray`, `people`? If someone changes the property `Favorite` on an object in the `favorites` array, does it automatically update that object in the `people` array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new array does not make copies. You have normal references to the original objects, so yes, if one of their properties changes, you will see the new value via both arrays. The arrays aren't connected at all after they're created either; the situation is the same as:

```
NSString * s = @"Cabbage crates coming over the briny!";
NSString * t = s;
```

You have two separate references to the same object.

You'll have to do explicit copies if you need them:

```
NSMutableArray * favorites = [NSMutableArray array];
for( Person * person in people ){
    if( [predicate evaluateWithObject:person] ){
        [favorites addObject:[person copy]];
    }
}
```

(Add an `autorelease` to the copied object if not using ARC (or, better, turn on ARC).)

This will require you to [implement `copy`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for your class.

Comment: no I actually prefer them to stay with references. I assume that by default objective C keeps this copy by reference.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "copy by reference".